# What is maximum and its computation in the function dist() {stats} in R?

Tags: r, clustering, similarities

In R, we can calculate a distance matrix using the method `"maximum"` in the function `dist()` in the stats package.

```
?dist
```

I don't understand to what dissimilarity measure it refers. It's saying "supremum norm" but I don't know what it means.

How is "maximum" computed?
Is there a dissimilarity measure that resemble "maximum"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supremum norm is the maximum absolute deviation in any dimension. i e

$$
d_{\text{max}}(\vec{x},\vec{y}):=\max_{\text{dimension }i} |x_i-y_i|
$$

This is also known as

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance

Comment: What do you call dimensions? If you're applying this to a matrix, it would be the maximum distance between the values contained in X and the values contained in Y?

Comment: Coordinates. The way you phrase it, it sounds as if these were *sets*, but they aren't. These are $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

Answer (score -3):

The help file for `dist` states

> Maximum distance between two components of x and y (supremum norm)

So the returned distance between two clusters `x` and `y` is the biggest distance between all pairs of members of `x` and `y`. If `x` and `y` are clusters made out of only one member each then it is simply the euclidean distance between the two.

Definition of supremum norm can be find [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SupremumNorm.html) or [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Supremum_Norm)

Comment: You seem to be confusing a distance between clusters with the underlying metric itself.  The sup norm reduces to Euclidean distance only in one dimension.  Is that what you mean by "points"?

Comment: Yeah I used points for when clusters are only one member. Edited to rid of the ambiguity

Comment: Your answer appears to be incorrect, based on applying `dist` to actual values.  Try, for instance, `dist(cbind(0:2, 2:4), method="maximum")`.  You will not get Euclidean distances between the rows of the matrix.